# LUKS encryption with non-interactive login on RHEL6

Tags: centos, encryption, fedora, luks, rhel-6

I need to have LUKS encryption on this system but during lab development I don't want to have to enter the password at the console each reboot. I'd like a way to set a simple password that can be passed and then later removed once the system is deployed.

http://atterer.org/linux-remove-disable-luks-encryption-password-on-disk-partition-crypttab-initrd

I found the above method but it's for debian and the paths don't exist. I tried to put a script with echo -n password that was executable as /boot/passphrase then updated /etc/crypttab to have keyscript=/boot/passphrase and it's not working.

Has anyone found a working method in fedora/RHEL6?

Answer (score 1):

Should just be able to list the password in the /etc/crypttab file and it'll automatically use that when it loads.

example :

```
crypt_home /dev/sda2 yourpasswordhere
```

Comment: Yes per the manpage it appears you can use a password or an **absolute** path to a file containing the password..

Answer (score 1):

Consider the different security issues with having your password in a file /etc/crypttab.  That being said you can create an entry with the password itself or you can create a file and use that as a password as well

Anytime you want to add a new password you can use

cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2

And then type in a password which can then be used to unlock

If you want to use a file, you can create a file of any contents, e.g.

dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/keyfile bs=1024 count=4

Then add that as a password

cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 /root/keyfile

And your corresponding entry in /etc/crypttab would be

crypt_home /dev/sda2 /root/keyfile

Wrote this up in more detail here if you need it:

http://geekswing.com/geek/how-to-encrypt-a-filesystem-on-redhat-6-4centos-6-4-linux-fips-or-no-fips/

Comment: if you are still monitoring your SU account could you have a look at this? http://superuser.com/questions/922893/luks-encrypted-volume-lost-upon-reboot