# LUKS encrypted volume lost upon reboot

Tags: linux, centos, encryption, luks, persistence

Using [this guide](http://geekswing.com/geek/how-to-encrypt-a-filesystem-on-redhat-6-4centos-6-4-linux-fips-or-no-fips/#comment-379) I encrypted a volume and am able to open and mount it manually.

The problem comes after rebooting.   On startup the system does not open the encrypted volume, nor is the decrypted alias available in /dev/mapper.

I can continue to create the alias manually using:

```
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/VolGroup/db00 db_fips
Enter passphrase for /dev/VolGroup/db00: [entered]
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# ll /dev/mapper/db_fips 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Jun  2 13:55 /dev/mapper/db_fips -> ../dm-7
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/db_fips 
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mount /dev/mapper/db_fips /db/
[root@dhcp100051 ~]#
```

I'm able to use my encrypted volume now, but when I issue `reboot` - everything is gone (including the data I wrote to /db/ after mkfs the filesystem).  I have to manually recreate it all... until  it is lost again on the next reboot.

*Note, this is a different problem from simply being asked to [enter the crypt password on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/792770/luks-encryption-with-non-interactive-login-on-rhel6).*

**What step am I missing to make the volume available after system reboot?**

---

Here is the full chain of commands I used in my Virtual Machine:

```
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mkdir /www/db-backup
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mv /db/* /www/db-backup
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# umount /db/
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# shred -v -n1 /dev/VolGroup/db00 
------------------------------------------------------------------
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...364MiB/2.0GiB 17%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...365MiB/2.0GiB 17%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...739MiB/2.0GiB 36%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...740MiB/2.0GiB 36%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.0GiB/2.0GiB 53%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.1GiB/2.0GiB 55%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.4GiB/2.0GiB 72%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.5GiB/2.0GiB 75%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.8GiB/2.0GiB 93%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...1.9GiB/2.0GiB 95%
shred: /dev/VolGroup/db00: pass 1/1 (random)...2.0GiB/2.0GiB 100%
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# cryptsetup -v --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/VolGroup/db00
Running in FIPS mode.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/VolGroup/db00 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter LUKS passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Command successful.
[root@dhcp100051 ~]#
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/VolGroup/db00 db_fips
Enter passphrase for /dev/VolGroup/db00: 
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# ll /dev/mapper/db_fips 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Jun  2 13:55 /dev/mapper/db_fips -> ../dm-7
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/db_fips 
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
131072 inodes, 523776 blocks
26188 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=536870912
16 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 37 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# mount /dev/mapper/db_fips /db/
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="37e5d6db-4265-4d0d-a10e-951f1bc4beb0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="f0079d24-daa2-472a-a557-384889dceb17" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="K16Dlj-6QR2-LemJ-iBnJ-z4fa-khuP-jv2BoA" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol01: UUID="425e6610-383b-4bb6-a3a3-1a68279a3460" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol05: UUID="fb04b576-fc59-409f-9049-c87b1c9c9437" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol04: UUID="2f88d451-03ac-4fe4-a21f-5ae2d786882b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol06: UUID="6aaccab0-7e4d-423b-89d4-ef54a36bf520" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol03: UUID="6814ecfc-b28e-4f50-823e-7ba7d5380d90" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-LogVol02: UUID="b40668b5-cc3a-450c-973b-c2b09885c7b7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-db00: UUID="a5320f38-2db4-4e71-8deb-c0169266c9fb" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/keyfile bs=1024 count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.0025613 s, 1.6 MB/s
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# chmod 0400 /root/keyfile 
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/VolGroup/db00 /root/keyfile
Enter any passphrase: 
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/VolGroup/db00 db_fips --key-file=/root/keyfile
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# vi /etc/crypttab 
## INSERT
db_fips UUID=”a5320f38-2db4-4e71-8deb-c0169266c9fb″ /root/keyfile
## SAVE AND CLOSE
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# date >> /db/date.txt
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# shutdown -r now
------------------------------------------------------------------
[REBOOTED]
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# ll /dev/mapper/db_fips
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# 
ls: cannot access /dev/mapper/db_fips: No such file or directory
[root@dhcp100051 ~]# ll /db
total 0
[root@dhcp100051 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution you have to setup a file [/etc/cryptab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crypttab) to define which volumes will be unlocked at boot time.

You may have to regenerate your initial ramdisk image.  This file has to be available before any filesystem is mounted.